# cannot install any packages in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, anaconda, package, pyinstaller

I was trying to install python packages in PyCharm. But I cannot see any Latest version as below:
[image]

I used pip to install some packages and it is not working and showing:

```
(base) C:\>pip install auto-py-to-exe
Collecting auto-py-to-exe
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1045)'))': /simple/auto-py-to-exe/
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1045)'))': /simple/auto-py-to-exe/
  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1045)'))': /simple/auto-py-to-exe/
  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1045)'))': /simple/auto-py-to-exe/
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1045)'))': /simple/auto-py-to-exe/
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/auto-py-to-exe/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/auto-py-to-exe/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1045)'))) - skipping
```

Then I tried with trusted host cmd:

(base) C:>pip install auto-py-to-exe --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org

Then it shows "Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement auto-py-to-exe (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for auto-py-to-exe"

So I tried to give it a version command:
(base) C:>pip install auto-py-to-exe from versions 2.7.5 --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org
However still shows the same issue here:

```
Collecting auto-py-to-exe
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement auto-py-to-exe (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for auto-py-to-exe
```

Then I am out... So if anyone has any ideas, please help. Many thanks.

Comment: Pycharm is annoying like this. If it's just for a single project, you could open the python shell inside pycharm and try it there.

Comment: check your pip version.

Comment: pip version is 10.0.1, cheers

Comment: Upgrade your pip to the latest version

Answer (score -1):

Follow the following https://datatofish.com/upgrade-pip/ to upgrade your pip.

You can also try manual installation: (https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/)

Download: https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py

```
python get-pip.py
```

Comment: Thank you @anoop, but it is not working. I check your link, first my interpreter is Anaconda 3.7. Then I still tried the cmd to upgrade pip, then it still shows the errer:Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] 
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in c:\programdata\anaconda\lib\site-packages (10.0.1)
twisted 18.7.0 requires PyHamcrest>=1.9.0, which is not installed.

Comment: Then I tried to install PyHamcrest, it shows the same error as my question...

Comment: @Alicejinx You can try manual installation I have added steps in my answer above.